# How do you make the C# winforms property grid show a property?

Tags: c#, winforms, propertygrid

I am creating a form which displays images in a slideshow. To make it possible to set these images during design time I am trying to create a property that will display in the property grid of the Form.
What is the correct way to do this? Currently I have tried the following, without success:

```
[Description("Stores the images that will be displayed on this form"),
Category("Data"),
DefaultValue(null),
Browsable(true)]
List<Image> images {get; set;}
```

Thank you for any help you can provide. I have compiled the application and made sure that an instance of the form was created, however I still do not see the property in the grid.

Comment: Is `images` public or private? I believe it needs to be public.

Comment: you are likely going to need a collection editor if this is for defining them at design time.

Comment: A UITypeEditor is required to be able to edit that list at design time.  There is not one built in the framework already, you have to make your own.  Apply the [Editor] attribute to tell the framework about it.  Consider using an ImageList instead, there *is* an UITypeEditor for that one.  Beware of its restrictions.